# Getting rmagick to work with Phusion Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, dreamhost, rmagick, passenger

I'm trying to deploy my app using  Phusion Passenger on DreamHost and I'm very close ...

I've unpacked my gems

```
[ecco]$ rake gems
(in /home/myuser/myurl.com/trunk)
 - [F] authlogic
    - [R] activesupport
 - [F] cancan
 - [F] formtastic
    - [R] activesupport >= 2.3.0
    - [R] actionpack >= 2.3.0
 - [F] paperclip
 - [F] rmagick
 - [F] uuidtools
```

I've got my gems referenced in my environment.rb

```
RAILS_GEM_VERSION = '2.3.5' unless defined? RAILS_GEM_VERSION
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'boot')
Rails::Initializer.run do |config|
  config.gem "authlogic"
  config.gem "cancan"
  config.gem "formtastic"
  config.gem "paperclip"
  config.gem "rmagick", :lib => "RMagick2"
  config.gem "uuidtools"
  config.time_zone = 'UTC'
end
```

If I comment out rmagick then the app starts (until I hit a page that uses rmagick obviously!). If I leave it in and go the app url I get the following  Phusion Passenger error:

> Missing these required gems: rmagick You're running: ruby 1.8.7.72 at /usr/bin/ruby1.8 rubygems 1.3.5 at /home/myuser/.gem/ruby/1.8, /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8 Run `rake gems:install` to install the missing gems.

Running ./script/console and ./script/server loads the environment without any problems.

Any help gratefully appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is known Dreamhost problem. 
Only solution is remove

```
config.gem "rmagick", :lib => "RMagick2"
```

and simply

```
require 'RMagick'
```